# Keys not found in dictionary after normalize them using NFKD

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use this piece of code to remove accent marks and symbols:

```
categories = ['Mn', 'Sc', 'Sk', 'Sm', 'So']
good_accents = {
    u'\N{COMBINING TILDE}',
    u'\N{COMBINING CEDILLA} 
}

return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text)
           if unicodedata.category(c) not in categories or c in good_accents)
```

This works pretty well but I have a problem. I load a tsv file into a dictionary and I search keys after normalize them. The problem is that even been equal, doesn't match. If I change NFKD to NFKC all works again, but accent marks are not remove (obviously). The thing is, what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried converting the values to `NFKC` after stripping accents but before looking them up?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the next code:

```
good_accents = {
    u'\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH TILDE}',
    u'\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE}',
    u'\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA}',
    u'\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA}'
}
categories = ['Mn', 'Sc', 'Sk', 'Sm', 'So']

return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', text)
            if unicodedata.category(c) not in categories or c in good_accents)
```

I don't really like it because I have more checks per character but... works.